# How to use laravel Multiple Auth Guard for same controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

laravel 5.2

I have and multiple auth Gard given below

```
Admin
Clients
Employee
```

i have

```
     
ItemController
        ->index.blade.php
        ->create.blade.php
        ->edit.blade.php

ItemKitController
        ->index.blade.php
        ->create.blade.php
        ->edit.blade.php
```

I want to use Client  and Employee Guard to access same Controller and view mention above.

is their any possible way.

Comment: I think you are trying to implement Policies using guard. Your use case should utilize a Policy.

Comment: NO i am not implementing policy

Comment: guards is for authentication, while policies are for authorization. In other words, you use guards to use JWT for API, and Normal Authentication for web. However, for different access rights as per your example, this is authorization, which can be done by Policies.

Comment: yes but i had implemented different guards for authentication 
Policy are for autorization

Comment: I want the multiple auth guard for same controller

Answer (score 6):

maybe you want something like this

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:Admin,Clients,Employee');
    }
```

in your controller

Answer (score 1):

You can use middleware like:

```
Route::group([ 'middleware' => ['Admin', 'Clients', 'Employee'] ], function(){
  Route::get('/Admin', 'AdminController@index');
  Route::get('/Clients', 'ClientsController@index');
  Route::get('/Employee', 'EmployeeController@index');

});
```

For instance, I have an admin middleware that checks if user id is 1

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use Log;

class AuthAdmin
{
    private $admins; // Admin ids

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $this->admins = config('custom.admins'); // get configs
        $user = Auth::user();

        if($user->id != 1)){
            // not admin, redirect home
            return redirect('/');
        }

      // is admin, let request continue
      return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then you have to add it to Kernel.php  "$routeMiddleware":

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,

        // Custom Middleware
        // Auth Admin
        'auth_admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthAdmin::class,
    ];
```

Then in my routes:

```
Route::group([ 'middleware' => ['auth_admin'] ], function(){

    // nobody can come to these routes but admins
    Route::get('/admin/index', 'AdminController@index');
});
```

Comment: I want  different auth guard for same controller ("auth:client", "auth:employee")